# React big calendar doesn't re-render after event change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

I am using React Big Calendar to build a to-do app. The event parameter will use a combination of API and props from parent. Now, I tried to add new event but the calendar did not render the newly created event.

I tried to confirm with `console.log` and another page that use the same data from parent, they all showed the new event. I have no idea what I was missing. I thought the calendar will automatically render if the event has changed.

*Note that I just simulate the change with a dummy button. The actual app will have data change from another page.*

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';

import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';
import './calendar.css'

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment)

export default function TaskSnapCalendar(props) {
    const [holidays, setHoliday] = useState([]);
    const HOLIDAY_API_URL = 'https://canada-holidays.ca/api/v1/holidays';

    // Fetching holiday data from API
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(HOLIDAY_API_URL)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setHoliday(data.holidays))
    }, [])
    const holidayEvents = [];
    holidays.forEach(holiday => {
        if (holiday.federal) {
            holidayEvents.push({
                title: holiday.nameEn,
                start: moment(holiday.date).toDate(),
                end: moment(holiday.date).toDate(),
                allDay: true,
                type: 'holiday',
                color: '#D71313'
            });
        }
    });

    // Fetching event data from props
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
    function taskToEvent(task) {
        return {
            title: task.title,
            start: moment(task.start).toDate(),
            end: moment(task.due).toDate(),
            allDay: task.due.includes('T') ? false : true,
        }
    }
    const newTasks = props.data.map(taskToEvent);
    useEffect(() => { setTasks(newTasks) }, []);

    // Combine data from API and props
    const events = [...holidayEvents, ...tasks];


    //////////// ADD DUMMY DATA ////////////
    var dummyTask = {
        "id": "200",
        "title": "DUMMY TASK",
        "status": "ongoing",
        "assigned_to": "DUMMY",
        "start": "2023-08-24",
        "due": "2022-08-25",
        "label": "DUMMY",
        "description": ""
      }
    const addMockTask = () => {
        props.modifyData([...props.data, dummyTask])
        setTasks([...tasks, taskToEvent(dummyTask)]);
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////



    return <div className='content'>
        <Calendar
            className='main-calendar'
            localizer={localizer}
            events={events}
            startAccessor="start"
            endAccessor={event => event.allDay ? moment(event.end).add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD') : event.end}
            showMultiDayTimes={true}
            eventPropGetter={event => {
                const backgroundColor = event.color;
                return { style: { backgroundColor } };
            }}
        />
        <button onClick={addMockTask}>TEST</button>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One, place your `taskToEvent(task)` method outside of your component function. No need to redefine it every time your component rerenders.

I would use a [reducer](https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer) to hold your multiple bits of state (holidays, tasks, events) and create dispatch case statements that handle updates to multiple state values simultaneously

```js
case 'CREATE_NEW_TASK': {
  const {task: newTask} = action;
  const {tasks, events, holidays} = state;
  const newTasks = [...tasks, newTask];
  const newEvents = [...events, taskToEvent(newTask)];
  return {
    ...state,
    tasks: newTasks,
    events: newEvents
  }
}
case 'ADD_HOLIDAYS': {
  const {holidays: updated = []} = action;
  const {holidays, events} = state;
  const newHolidays = [...holidays, updated];
  const federalDays = updated.filter(({federal}) => federal);
  const newEvents = [...events, federalDays.map(holidayToTask)];
  return {
    ...state,
    holidays: newHolidays,
    events: newEvents
  }
}
```